# Add onclick event to array items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to iterate over an array and apply an onclick event to each item. I'm hoping to be able to click each of my divs and have them console log their value. Right now I'm stuck on how to apply the onclick to each div. I'm new to JS, so I'm not completely of why I shouldn't make a function inside of a loop like JSBin is complaining about. I've messed around with a lot of different ways to do this, but am truly stuck...

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kikazo/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
function numberTrack() {

  var gridItems = document.getElementsByClassName("grid");

  for (var i = 0; i < gridItems[0].length; i ++) {
    gridItems.onclick = function(){
      alert("hello");
    };
  }
}

numberTrack();
```

Comment: are you allowed to use JQuery?

Comment: Put the code in the question...

Comment: my first thought also :), read about the $('div').on('click',function(){})

Comment: Since I'm just learning JS, i don't really want to add in all the extras of JQuery. I want to keep things as simple as possible right now.

Comment: the code is in the question @epascarello

Comment: A link !== code in question. Use stackoverflow snippets or the code block.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Thank you! @epascarello

Answer (score 1):

JSBin is complaining because it wants you to declare the function outside the for loop and then assign it inside the for loop.  This is more efficient then what you are currently doing, which is assigning a new anonymous function to each item in the array.  All those identical functions will have to be created and stored separately in memory.

You can do something like this instead:

```
function alertHello() {
  alert("hello");
}

for (var i = 0; i < gridItems.length; i++) {
    gridItems[i].onclick = alertHello;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("divs");    <--- array of divs

for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {

    c[i].onclick = function() {

        console.log(this.value);

    }

}
```

Comment: in your JSBin code "gridItems[0]" is not an array, its an element in the array

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all the items in the gridItems collection, And inside the loop, get each item using the iterator i value.

```
function handleClick()
{
  alert("hello");
}
function numberTrack() {

  var gridItems = document.getElementsByClassName("grid");

  for (var i = 0; i < gridItems.length; i ++) {
      gridItems[i].onclick = handleClick;
  }
}

numberTrack();
```

If you are allowed to use jQuery, you can bind the event to items like this.

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on("click",".grid",function(e){
      var item =$(this);
      alert(item.html())
  })
})
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/ninehizoxi/1/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working jsBin sample